# Spring boot register to more than one registry?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-consul

Does anyone know how to get spring boot to registrer to more than one registry service, e.g. eureka and consul.

We were hoping to run them in parallel for a while before the switch.

```
Field registration in org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistryAutoConfiguration$ServiceRegistryEndpointConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- eurekaRegistration: defined by method 'eurekaRegistration' in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.class]
- consulRegistration: defined by method 'consulRegistration' in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/consul/serviceregistry/ConsulAutoServiceRegistrationAutoConfiguration.class]
```

Comment: check the comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762759/how-to-register-a-spring-cloud-app-to-both-eureka-and-consul

Comment: Yea i read that, but ti doesn't give much info. Was hoping to read somethign about creating our own DiscoveryClient or some special override that can do it.

Also the comment by Spencer didn't say which pr number it was, and i can't seem to find that ticket or any merges relating to it, i've also updated to use the latest incase it has been merged but no luck.